# ssis package : configration file destination values are not reflecting in package

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have  created a ssis package to migrate records from flat file to sql server  database table. I want to do this task with configuration file but when i change the database server name from  local machine to server, in config file, it does not migrate the data to the new destination server.

Help me!

Comment: in which version you are working 2008 or 2012 BIDS environment

Comment: sql server 2014 and visual studio 2015

Comment: go through project parameters and Environmental deployment

Comment: You should be using Visual Studio 2013 to develop SSIS packages for SQL Server 2014.

Comment: Is there any specific reason to use VS2013 with SQL SERVER 2014 ?